# Parsing information from a jQuery POST request?

Tags: jquery, ajax, api, post

I have been trying for 2 weeks to get and parse information from an API of this site:
http://www.imei.info/api/imei/docs/
I'm new to web development (RT C++ developer), I can't seem to get is to work.

my code here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript">
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("input").keyup(function () {
                txt = $("input").val();
                $.post("http://www.imei.info/api/checkimei/", { login: "XXX", password: "XXX", imei: "XXX" }, function (data) {
                    $("span").html(data);
                    $('#message').html(data);
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Start typing a name in the input field below:</p>
    First name:

    <input type="text" />
    <div id="message"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean "parse?" It's JSON, so jQuery will likely parse the string for you. In that case `data` is a native JavaScript object and you can use it as you please.

Answer (score 0):

It's returning a JSON response. You can do var responseObj = JSON.parse(data) and access the fields like responseObj.imei or responseObj.brand